# interaction beetween firefox xul estension and a web page

Tags: javascript, firefox, html, xul

I'm writing a firefox xul extension, and I must have an interaction beetween the web page and extension.

Example: If I press a link from the page I want to call a function in the xul extension.
Anyone know if there is a way?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. You'll need to access page content with the `content` object.

In your extension code you can select all links and then add an eventListener:

```
allLinks = content.document.getElementsByTagName("a"),

for (var i=0, il=allLinks.length; i<il; i++) {
    elm = allLinks[i];
    elm.addEventListener("click", nowclicked, false);
}
```

And then your event listener would look something like:

```
nowclicked : function () {
    alert("a linked was clicked!");
}
```

If you need a working example, I've modified the [Link Target Finder](http://robertnyman.com/2009/01/24/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/) extension by Robert Nyman to add an alert when links are clicked. The modified code is in [linkTargetFinder.js](https://github.com/christi3k/link-target-finder/blob/master/chrome/content/linkTargetFinder.js).

Comment: mmm, I have some questions.

Can I have my link: 
  <a href="javascript:retriveInfo('photo')">Photo</a>
  <a href="javascript:retriveInfo('usersLIst')">Userlist</a>



what I have to write in the .js file of mine extension?

instead of alert("a link"); can I write retrivePhoto();

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to give the extension access to the actual photo (binary image data) that is at the link?

Comment: sorry I'm not be able to speak english very well



what I want to do is call from a web page that I create a function of my firefox extension's, not a function in a file that I import inside the page, but the .js that I create for my extension

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Take a look at the example I linked to. The nowclicked() function is inside the extension's javascript. If you don't want to execute the function using an event, then you can follow the method @Kashif posted (less secure).

Answer (score 0):

See MDN example for [Sending data from unprivileged document to chrome document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages#Sending_data_from_unprivileged_document_to_chrome).

Basically, in your chrome code you have to add a listener:

```
// The last value is a Mozilla-specific value to indicate untrusted content is allowed to trigger the event.
document.addEventListener("MyExtensionEvent", function(e) {myExtension.myListener(e);}, false, true);
```

and fire the event from content script. Note that document in the following is the `contentDocument` not `XulDocument`

```
var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
evt.initEvent("MyExtensionEvent", true, false);
element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```